# word embedding code, trying to implement utf-8 checker

Tags: python

I'm having trouble getting my code to run properly. I tried to implement a utf-8 checker but it's causing problems for other parts of the code.

this is the code:

```
pd = codecs.open("r8-train-all-terms.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
# pd = open("r8-test-all-terms.txt", errors="strict", encoding="utf-8")

train = pd.read_csv("r8-train-all-terms.txt", header=None, sep='\t')
test = pd.read_csv('r8-test-all-terms.txt', header=None, sep='\t')
```

this is the error im getting:

```
File "C:\Users\smust\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    train = pd.read_csv("r8-train-all-terms.txt", header=None, sep='\t')
File "C:\Users\smust\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\codecs.py", line 743, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: okay, sorry I haven't asked a question before.

Comment: How is your utf-8 checker related to CSV? You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the utf-8 checker for the file that's being read with csv. I'm not sure how to get it so that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your local variable `pd` is overriding the pandas import that you really need. Rename your open file handles to something else:

```
import pandas as pd
fh = codecs.open("r8-train-all-terms.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
fh2 = open("r8-test-all-terms.txt", errors="strict", encoding="utf-8")

train = pd.read_csv(fh, header=None, sep='\t')
test = pd.read_csv(fh2, header=None, sep='\t')
```

Pandas `read_csv()` can take a filename as well, and some encoding parameters, so this might be a second way to do the same thing:

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv("r8-train-all-terms.txt", header=None, sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
test = pd.read_csv('r8-test-all-terms.txt', header=None, sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8', encoding_errors = 'strict')
```